# Creating a raster with point count as cell value?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I have a `PostGIS` table with Point geometries in it. I want to create a raster object where each cell value is the number of points within a given raster cell. Cells with zero points in it can be 0, `Null` or anything else that lets me differentiate it from a plausible `count` output.

What I did so far is to create a new raster ([adapted from this tutorial](https://nronnei.github.io/blog/2017/03/creating-rasters-from-scratch-in-postgis/)):

```
CREATE TABLE public.sampleraster(
  rid SERIAL primary key, rast raster
);

INSERT INTO public.sampleraster(rast)
SELECT ST_AddBand(
  -- Make empty raster
  ST_MakeEmptyRaster(
      5000, -- Raster width x (in pixels)
      3000, -- Raster width y (in pixels)
      -75, -- Upper left X coordinate
      45, -- Upper left Y coordinate
      0.008333333333333, -- X Cell Resolution (in degrees)
      0.008333333333222, -- Y Cell Resolution (in degrees)
      0, -- X skew
      0, -- Y skew
      4326 -- SRID (WGS 84)
    ),
    ARRAY [
      ROW(
        1,  -- Band index: sets this as the first band
        '32BUI'::text,  -- Pixel Type (string rep of ST_BandPixelType types)
        NULL,  -- Initialized pixel value
        NULL   -- Nodata Value
      )
    ]::addbandarg[]
);
```

The Problem is now to fill the raster with count values. I'm counting the Points per cell like this

```
SELECT
round (st_x (geom) / 0.008333333333333) * 0.008333333333333 lon,
round (st_y (geom) / 0.008333333333222) * 0.008333333333222 lat,
count(*) ct
FROM sampledata
WHERE
st_x (geom) BETWEEN -75 AND -33.33333
AND 
st_y (geom) BETWEEN 10 AND 35

GROUP BY round (st_x (geom) / 0.008333333333333), round (st_y (geom) / 0.008333333333222)
ORDER BY round (st_x (geom) / 0.008333333333333), round (st_y (geom) / 0.008333333333222)
```

Now I'm struggling to get the values into the raster. I think I need to get the values in a 2D array (going from the [tutorial](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetValues.html)), but I don't know how to go about this. Any ideas here?

If somebody is interested in recreating the issue, you can use this query to generate a bunch of random points in the study area:

```
CREATE TABLE sampledata AS
WITH x AS
    (select generate_series (1,1000),
     st_setSRID(st_makepoint(
        (random()*50)::float - 120,
        (random()*25)::float + 30),
     4326) geom,
     random()*100::int num_a)
SELECT geom FROM x;
```

Comment: if i look in postgis documentation, what you want to achieve seems to be possible with St_SetValues and a count of points at the given coordinate. so try to make a table with coordX, coordY, Value and then use St_setValues.  Then, syntax would be St_SetValues(raster, nb_band (1), coordX, coordY, Value)

Comment: Exactly as suggested  by Maximilien. As a general rule, don't use zero in place of null, it is bad practice, and can lead to some nasty to find statistical bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the [PostGIS](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons) Addons and have a look at ST_ExtractToRaster() with the COUNT_OF_POINTS method. Should go like this after you created a reference raster:

```
CREATE TABLE count_of_point_coverage AS
SELECT ST_ExtractToRaster(
         ST_AddBand(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(rast), '32BF'::text, -9999, -9999), 
         'public', 
         'sampledata', 
         'geom', 
          NULL, 
         'COUNT_OF_POINTS') rast
FROM sampleraster;
```

You need to have an index on the geometry column of your point table.

More details in the "Method 2" section of this post: http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed. Seems like it's also a lot faster than my approach.

Comment: I'm glad it`s still working. Which PostGIS version are you using?

Comment: I used it in two settings, both worked without issues:
 (1) Manjaro Linux, Postgres 11.4, PostGIS 2.5.2 r17328
 (2) Windows Server 2012, Postgres 11.1, PostGIS 2.5.1 r17027

Comment: I am struggling to run 'ST_ExtractToRaster' and getting the ERROR:  function st_extracttoraster(raster, unknown, unknown) does not exist. Is there a way to setup this function? I am on postGIS 3.1

Comment: You have to install the PostGIS Addons script to define the function.